# Hadoop Remove unnecessary \n in the input files

Tags: hadoop, input, split

I have a large input file, values are pipe delimited. And there are 20 values in a row. after 19th pipe, if new line character comes, that is a record.

But my input file is having \n not only after 19 pipes but also in the other values. sample line looks like this...

101101|this\nis my sample|12547|sample\nxyz|......(19th pipe)|end of record\n

I am new to Hadoop and I don't know how to divide lines to create key value pairs based on this condition.

Another related question I have is, input split happens at the client side and if I have to split the input file conditionally on the client side(one machine), will it not be very slow considering the large file? Please help.

Answer (score 0):

In Hive NULL column values are represented as "\N" that's the default behaviour of Hive. This is done to differentiate NULL and "NULL" (string NULL).

If you don't want \N to appears to appear in your export you can use COALESCE UDF.

Roughly your query may look like this

```
SELECT
   COALESCE (my_column, '') AS my_column
FROM
   my_table
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I am not trying to remove the NULL. I am trying to remove only \n from text. For example in my sample line above, second column value in the input file is 'this\nis my sample'. I need to remove \n from it and I should get 'this is my sample' as value.

Comment: Ok! If you are still looking out for solution i reckon you can write some sort of shell script to replace \n characters. Let me know how you go.